# How to make an payment gateway in flutter, that works in both the platforms

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My question is, we need to write codes for both the native platforms or just flutter dart code is enough to run in both the platforms?

Comment: What are the platforms you are talking about? Do you mean mobile/web/desktop? If so, have you ever looked for an official document? [`flutter`](https://flutter.dev/) Also.. Im sry but, I don't think that question is suitable for StackOverflow. Please refer to stackoverflow's [`tour`](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [`how-to-ask`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: no, here platforms means Android and IOS only, and yes i read the flutter docs, and also the pub dev. but what i want is not there, so i asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean in-app purchase? you can use this package
https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

Comment: No, i just want to create my own payment gateway in pub dev, so that it can work in both the platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [flutter_paystack](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_paystack) package which fully supports Android as well as iOS

Comment: thanks @Aakash, it will help me as a reference, to create my own gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [stripe_sdk](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_sdk)  package which fully supports Android , IOS as well as Web